# Best way to submit form values to the database in Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter, form-submit

I'm pretty new on Code Igniter.

I've read some tutorials about this, but some of them are outdated and the rest are just not clear for me.

So , I got the my first form coded using the [form helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) (finally! :P) - what is the best way (and how to do this) to submit the data in my form to the database?

Also, is it good to store the form data in the model like this:

```
$data['login'] = 'Login:';
$data['password'] = 'Password:';
$data['rpassword'] = 'Repeat Password:';

$data['flogin'] = array(
    'name' => 'login',
    'class' => 'login_box'
);

$data['fpassword'] = array(
    'name' => 'password',
    'class' => 'login_box'
);

$data['frpassword'] = array(
    'name' => 'rpassword',
    'class' => 'login_box'
);
```

And display it with the view like this:

```
<?=
    $this->load->helper('form');
    echo form_open();
?>

<div class="container">
    <?= $login ?> <?= form_input($flogin); ?><br/>
    <?= $password ?> <?= form_password($fpassword); ?><br/>
    <?= $rpassword ?> <?= form_password($frpassword); ?><br/>
    <? echo form_submit("submit", "Save"); ?>

    <? echo form_close(); ?>

</div>
```

Or maybe you have any better solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

Too your second question, my back-end coder and I have tried everything under the sun and argued this a million times over.  Basically it comes down to situation.  If you have a view that is used repitavly to simple draw in data for another view, then your best off using codigniter's parse class to send the values in an easy to use array that ci can parse through on your html and thus fill in the gaps.  However, if you have a view full of dynamic data, we typically do the following for initial data:

In CI:

```
$bob = 'some data1'
$jill = date(); // or whatever
// continue to get your data as needed
// then prep specific vars with your front end guy for the data, remember,
// every initial key in your data array becomes $key in the view
// when done gather your data, just before view call
$data = array(
    'title' => $bob,
    'bodyPiece' => $jill,
    // etc...
);
$this->load->view('someviewWithAFormInIt.php', $data);
```

In View:

```
<html ....
    <title><?= $bob; ?></title>
    <form ....
        <input name="inpBob" value="<?= $jill; ?>"
```

Recieving the data from your form is fairly easy, though if you're loading it to a DB, mke sure to use the conditional param as TRUE to let CI's xss filter make it safer

```
$this->input->post('inpBob', TRUE);
```

And for your question about database submission, I relly can't answer any better than [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)<--

It's called Active Record and it's FREAKING AWESOME!!! Spend some time reading that link I provided which is CI's doc on this class called Active Record, and you'll never wanna make another type of db code call other than this, i promise!  It is beyond super easy!

Comment: So you're suggesting to use raw HTML for forms instead of CI's one? I mean: `<input name="something" value="something123"/>` instead of `echo form_input(array('name' => 'something', 'value' => 'something123'));`?

Comment: you can or if you really want to feel secure, what i was getting to, is once you learn that format, you use the form class to create a data varaiable that you pop in your view data array, then on the view `<?= $myForm ?>` will echo your data variable to the page thus creating the form. In development we've had to do it the other way for simply putting everything together, and then go back through and go to cleaner methods during a beta testing.  We've found that tryig to create the form php side and echo html side makes debugging and reviewing a rel pain in the &#!.

Comment: fyi, part of the reason for my update just being links, is because jsFiddle is down today as well and so i cant give u a working example